# The type or namespace name 'Rotator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I imported some assets and this error keeps popping up. I'm fairly new to Unity and C#.

This is part of the script that gives me trouble. I honestly don't understand what is the problem with "Rotator".

```
public enum PetState {Run,Walk,Idle,Lay,Sleep,Jump,Eat,Sniff,Sit,Celebrate }
public class PetController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PetState m_PetState;

    private Animator m_Animator;
    private Rotator m_Rotator;

    public GameObject m_LookAtTransformPrefab;
    private Transform m_LookAtTransform;  
}
```

I think this is where the problem must occur with the Rotator.

```
void SetUpLookAt()
{
  m_Rotator = GetComponent<Rotator>();
  m_Rotator.m_Target = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
  GameObject m_LookAtTransformObject = Instantiate(m_LookAtTransformPrefab, transform.position + (transform.forward * .1f), transform.rotation);
  Rotator m_LookAtRotator = m_LookAtTransformObject.GetComponent<Rotator>();
  m_LookAtTransformObject.transform.parent = m_Rotator.m_Target.transform;
  m_LookAtRotator.m_Target = transform.parent.gameObject;
  m_LookAtRotator.m_Speed = m_Rotator.m_Speed;
  m_LookAtRotator.m_ReverseRotation = m_Rotator.m_ReverseRotation;
  m_LookAtTransform = m_LookAtTransformObject.transform;
}

void SetAnimatorBool(string m_AnimatorBool)
{
        foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter m_AnimatorParameter in m_Animator.parameters)
        {
            if (m_AnimatorParameter.name != m_AnimatorBool)
                m_Animator.SetBool(m_AnimatorParameter.name, false);
            else
            {
                if (m_Animator.GetBool(m_AnimatorParameter.name) != true)
                    m_Animator.SetBool(m_AnimatorParameter.name, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the script that contains the `Rotator` type?

Comment: Could you give more details about the error ? What exactly are we looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Surely "`Rotator`" is a class defined in another script (or assembly). To use `Rotator` class in this script you need to use the reference of WHAT script is defining `Rotator`, which probably is `Rotator` script itself.

The simplest way is in the header of your script to put:

```
using Rotator;
```

So your script will look like:

```
using Rotator;

public enum PetState {Run,Walk,Idle,Lay,Sleep,Jump,Eat,Sniff,Sit,Celebrate }
public class PetController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PetState m_PetState;

    private Animator m_Animator;
    private Rotator m_Rotator;

    public GameObject m_LookAtTransformPrefab;
    private Transform m_LookAtTransform;
    
}
```

To compare, when you use a "`Button`" class inside one script, you need the `using UnityEngine.UI;`, right? This is the same, you are telling your script that your "`Button`" is referenced from the library `UnityEngine.UI`

Comment: Thank you for your help but that didn't work.

Comment: You're welcome. But try to attach more information not simply "didn't work", try to attach which error message is popin up now, and this kind of stuff so we can try different solutions ^^

Comment: Sorry, fairly new to Stackoverflow as well. Well, I get the same error again:
 
Assets\Adorable Pets\Scripts\PetController.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Rotator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) - `using Rotator;`

Comment: Don't worry Szabi ^^ try to attach an image of your script PetController.cs. If Rotator is underlined in red (and you are working in visual studio) try to left-click on the underlined Rotator and press alt+enter, and tell me what appears (it should recommend you the assembly of Rotator if exists in your solution)